# value below was evaluated just now

Tags: typescript, rxjs, nestjs

I have a method that returns an Observable as follows:

```
public myMethod(params): Observable<CertainType> {
    // some code goes here;
    return defer(() => this.customHttp.request<XML>(config, ctx)).pipe(
    map(
            (xmlRes: string) => {
                const xmlHandler = new strongsoap.soap.XMLHandler();
                const rawSFResponse = xmlHandler.xmlToJson(null, xml, null);
                const res = rawSFResponse["Body"]["SFResponse"]["SFResult"];
                // more code goes here;
            }
        )
    )
}
```

The problem with this piece of code is that I receive an error in the console that says
`Cannot read property 'SFResult' of undefined`.
And if I try console-logging the `rawSFResponse` object it gets printed out but when I click on it it says "value below was evaluated just now".

As far as I understand it happens because this statement `res = rawSFResponse["Body"]["SFResponse"]["SFResult"];` is executed before the res object is fully formed, namely at the moment it gets executed the content of the `SFResult` field is still undefined.
Is it correct? If so, then what would be the best way to wait for it to be formed. Maybe I have to wrap the parsing function into a promise and then use `await` on it?

Comment: I guess this is more like a soap xml handling issue. If the parsing happens asynchronously, the question is how can you wait for the result to be fully parsed. I don't know that library, but is there a possibility to get the result through callback you pass to the parser or as a promise from the parser?

Comment: @Wilt With this lib it should not happen asynchronously, i don't know how else to explain the source of  the 'value below was evaluated just now' error. There's another custom parsing function here, and it returns a Promise but it's hard to use it inside the construction I've chosen. Maybe that behavior is because I convert a Promise into an Observable? I've just run out of ideas.

Comment: The message you get is nicely explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57843750/1697459). It does suggest the object has changed, so I suspect something asynchronous going on. But try once to do `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rawSFResponse));` then you get a snapshot of the object in console before it changed.